# Assign rows of a Matrix to a new Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix named v1 and I want to create another matrix named matriz1 that has only the items of the length of v1*2/3

```
v1=np.matrix('1,2;3,4;2,6;4,5')
distancia=len(v1)
distancia=distancia*2/3
matriz1=np.matrix
print(distancia)
k=0
print()
print()
print('matriz1')
for k in range(0,(int(distancia))):
    matriz1[k]=v1[k]
    k=k+1
print(matriz1)
```

The error is: TypeError

```
      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-206-1ed800e332a1> in <module>()
     77 print('matriz1')
     78 for k in range(0,(int(distancia))):
---> 79     matriz1[k]=v1[k]
     80     k=k+1
     81 print(matriz1)

TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

I know I am not defining a length for that matrix. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Consider properly initializing `matriz1` like `matriz1 = np.empty((3,2))`.

Comment: But imagine that v1 is a matrix which it is created somewhere else and I do not know the length nor the elements. I just want that the new matrix has 2/3 its length with the elements of the 2/3 length. Not the v1 matrix specificly @VasilisG.

Comment: In this case try something like: `matriz1=np.empty((int(v1.shape[0] * 2/3), v1.shape[1]))` to get the 2/3 of the matrix length. Also replace your last print statement with `print(matriz1.astype(int))` to get them as integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't create a new matrix, but just give `np.matrix` another name `matriz1`.

For numpy, you don't need loops, just use index slicing:

```
v1 = np.matrix('1,2;3,4;2,6;4,5')
distancia = len(v1) * 2 // 3
matriz1 = v1[:distancia].copy()
```

Comment: Gives an error: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: @M.K have to use integer division `//`.